# I am having a border issue with the :before pseudo element

Tags: css

I am attempting to create a second border using the :before pseudo element to keep my mark-up clean. However, I am having some problems getting it to work properly. Perhaps you could shed some light on the issue? The border is supposed to be 5px in height and it should be placed above the primary header.

You can view the code live at http://anelegantdesign.com/issue -- I appreciate any help you can give me.

EDIT: The border is supposed to look like this: http://screencast.com/t/hUDBvDiL

Comment: your -1 z-index is hiding the pseudoelement completely

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but the reason the `#site-header:before` was not visible is because it has a `z-index:-1`. When I changed it to zero, it appeared.

Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not quite. Check my edit for details on what it should look like.